# Трудности с пониманием работы функции

Tags: строки, swift, функции, перестановка

Не могу до конца понять, как работает рекурсия в этой функции. Функция выводит через print() все перестановки символов

```
func allLexicographicRecur (_ string: [String.Element], _ data: [String], _ last: Int, _ index: Int){
    var length = string.count-1
    var data = data
    for i in 0...length {
        data[index] = String(string[i])
        if index == last {
            print(data)
        }else{
            allLexicographicRecur(string, data, last, index+1)
        }

    }
}

allLexicographicRecur(["a", "b", "c"], ["","",""], 2, 0)
```

Вывод:

```
["a", "a", "a"]
["a", "a", "b"]
["a", "a", "c"]
["a", "b", "a"]
["a", "b", "b"]
["a", "b", "c"]
["a", "c", "a"]
["a", "c", "b"]
["a", "c", "c"]
["b", "a", "a"]
["b", "a", "b"]
["b", "a", "c"]
["b", "b", "a"]
["b", "b", "b"]
["b", "b", "c"]
["b", "c", "a"]
["b", "c", "b"]
["b", "c", "c"]
["c", "a", "a"]
["c", "a", "b"]
["c", "a", "c"]
["c", "b", "a"]
["c", "b", "b"]
["c", "b", "c"]
["c", "c", "a"]
["c", "c", "b"]
["c", "c", "c"]
```

Буду очень благодарен за объяснение того, как данная функция переставляет символы.

Answer (score 1):

Функция ничего не переставляет.

На каждом (k-ом) уровне рекурсии она заполняет k-ю ячейку списка  возможными символами по порядку.

Таким образом, на нулевом уровне формируются списки `[a..][b..][c..]`, в каждый из которых на следующем уровне добавляются новые символы и так далее.

После того, как на k-м уровне ветвь, начинающаяся с a, завершена, k-й элемент **заменяется** на b и так далее.

Всего 3^n вариантов.